# Lowercase gamma in mhchem environment with fontspec

Tags: fontspec, mhchem

I'm trying to use \gamma inside the mhchem environment, and it refuses to render the correct glyph. Alpha and beta work, as does Uppercase \Gamma. I have tried this with other fonts e.g. Roboto and the same behaviour occurs.

Is this a bug and is there a workaround? MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Bright}
\begin{document}

\ce{\alpha}
\ce{\gamma}
$\alpha$
$\gamma$

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

using LuaLatex. With XeTex, a crossed box appears.

EDIT:

[Logfile link here:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/axmaiy94iuarbt2/debug.log?dl=0)  (XeTex)
[Logfile (LuaLatex)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbhtpyyi2b2fu77/debug_lualatex.log?dl=0)

[!
[Output of \printchemgreekalphabet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAbpU.png)]

FINAL EDIT: Shamefully, updating to the newest mactex distribution fixed the problem. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Are you compiling with Xe- or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: This is what I get: [click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsxOY.png)

Comment: It clearly works for you OK then. Any ideas why this might not be working on my setup? No errors or even warnings are thrown on my machine.

Comment: Show the log-file. At best from lualatex.

Comment: Show the *complete* log-file. The interesting parts are not in the snippet.

Comment: Does `\printchemgreekalphabet`show the complete alphabet?

Comment: Edited to reflect comments

Comment: Umm, you claim the log file was produced by LuaLaTeX, but the header line says it was compiled with XeLaTeX. By the way, if I compile your file with LuaLaTeX (MacTeX2017, LuaTeX 1.0.4), I experience no problems at all.

Comment: added LuaLatex logfile too

Comment: We cannot see the image, because it's on DropBox. Insert it with the correct interface, please.

Comment: I tried that but it exceeded the char count for a post. The Dropbox link should ve viewable to all with the link?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by updating software